# qpdf has started throwing "External component has thrown an exception" on qpdf_init()

Tags: .net, iis, qpdf

As of today, qpdf stopped working on my server. It's been running for a few weeks without any issues, but today I am getting a "External component has thrown an exception" error, I am not getting this issue on my dev machine, only on the server once published.

I have restarted IIS, restarted the whole machine, recycled the app pool, tried the 32 and 64 bit version's (I get the program attempted to load in wrong format error for the 32 bit dlls), tried older versions of qpdf and now i'm pretty stumped as I don't even have a lead from the error message.

The project is currently in vb.net, the code used to reproduce this would be as follows:

```
'Importing the function here
<DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function qpdf_init() As IntPtr
    End Function

'try to use it here, works fine on dev, worked on server last week but now throws "External component has thrown an exception"

Public Shared Function LinearisePdf(fileName As String) As String

        Dim qpdf As IntPtr = qpdf_init()

end function
```

The stack trace from the server throwing the error looks like this:

```
External component has thrown an exception. at DocumentManager.PdfOcr.qpdf_init() at DocumentManager.PdfOcr.LinearisePdf(String fileName) in ...
```

Any ideas on how I can continue to work towards resolving this by getting more detail about what the error is, or maybe some more things to try?

Server is:
Windows server 2016 Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.2828)
Internet Information Services (Version 10.0.14393.0)
I have downloaded qpdf v 8.4.0 msvc64 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/8.4.0/qpdf-8.4.0-bin-msvc64.zip/download)

Comment: In my opinoin for a workaround, you could try to use any other dll. If possible could you please provide some detailed code?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the machine privileges for the user running the application pool had changed, once we set it back to machine administrator, it stopped throwing this exception.